# Matrix Error after installation

Tags: matrix, error

I've just purchased and installed Matrix, and I'm receiving this error when I attempt to create a new Channel Field in any Channel.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

When I uninstall Matrix, it goes back to working normal with no issues.

EE 2.7, Matrix 2.5.6

```
Unable to load requested field type file: ft.dww_flickr.php.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a conflict between Matrix and your version of Flickr for ExpressionEngine fieldtype. First, uninstall both add-ons. Re-install Matrix. Does it work?

If so, then make sure you have the latest version of [Flickr for EE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/flickr) and install it.

If you have the same problem again, you'll have to contact the add-on makers to see if one of them can fix the bug for you.

UPDATE:

Found this: https://github.com/brettdewoody/Flickr-for-ExpressionEngine/pull/2

DWW Flickr is now EEhive Flickr, so definitely read the link above.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling the plugin, and it still does not work. I'm not convinced that the EEHive Flickr plugin is what it's asking for - as the file listed in the error "ft.dww_flickr.php" is not listed in that package you linked to... Maybe the filename was changed with an update? Is there a way to view enabled plugins directly in the database - and possibly disable it from there? * Update * Just checked the fieldtypes table in the DB, and they are in fact different plugins. I'll try disabling it there and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Removing the DWW Flickr fieldtype from the fieldtypes table fixed my issue. It was no longer being used, so I didn't worry about migration.

Thanks!